# after converting c# to vb.net there is an error "properties" is not member

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I tried to open in the original project built-in c# there is no error but after I convert to vb.net then there is an error "'Properties' is not a member of" even though the png file is still in the resources folder

thanks
jack

```
            Me.BtnCerrar.Image = Global.COMPLETE_FLAT_UI.Properties.Resources.Close
error :Error    1   'Properties' is not a member of 'COMPLETE_FLAT_UI'. C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop\ModernFlat-GUI-Version-Completa-C-Sharp-master\COMPLETE_FLAT_UI\FormListaClientes.designer.vb   133 34  COMPLETE_FLAT_UI
```

[image: 'Properties' is not a member of]

[image: view]

Comment: If you delete the text at the end of the line so that you only have COMPLETE_FLAT_UI, then type the . then intellisense should display the options available. The syntax required to access the 'Close' image may need an altered syntax.

Comment: `Me.BtnCerrar.Image = My.Resources.Close`

Comment: @dr.null , This is the best solution for me and you can answer as an answer from you

Comment: You're welcome Jacki. You can post that. GTG :) Good day.

Comment: @dr.null , You are the best and you are indeed my teacher and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from @dr.null . He is indeed the best teacher for me.

```
Me.BtnCerrar.Image = My.Resources.Close
```